# How do they know about being stung

Tags: the-maze-runner

In *Maze Runner* the characters are constantly saying no one survives a night in the maze, but yet Gally is surprised when Ben gets stung asking “What? During the day?” Implying they have only ever been stung at night. Which can’t have happened because no one has come back after a night in the maze. So how do they already know about the “changing” because for them to know the effects they must have had cases of it.
So I’m quite confused can someone explain this please.

Comment: Also https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24912/what-was-doing-the-stinging-in-maze-runner?rq=1